# close Flutter MapView programically

Tags: android-mapview, flutter

I want to close MapView dialog when user select the place on map or top on a action Toolbar button but there is no method like `show()` that close the map programmatically.
I want something like below code :

```
 mapView.onToolbarAction.listen((id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        mapView.close();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [dismiss()](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/map_view/0.0.12/map_view/MapView/dismiss.html) method that you can use rather than close().

You can use like this:

```
mapView.onToolbarAction.listen((id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        mapView.dismiss();
    }
 });
```